# CSS center image animation in the middle of the page

Tags: css, css-transitions, center

I have the following code that transitions an image from the bottom to the top, but I need this to center. On my colleagues screen it is centered, but on mine it is more at the top. Is there a way to ensure it is centered on all screens? (without breaking the rest of my CSS lol)

**JS:**

```
const showAlerts = () => {
  getElements().forEach((alert) => {
    focus-alert.style.display = "";
    focus-alert.style.bottom = "25%"; // <--- *This is what does the transition to the 'center'*
  });
};
```

**HTML**

```
    <div class="mobile-wrapper">
        <div id="mobile" class="focus-alert">
            <img src="assets/images/mobile-moments-away-img.png">
            <img id="mobile-close-btn" class="mobile-close-btn" src="assets/images/mobile-close-button-img.png" onclick="handleClose(this)">
            <img id="mobile-continue-btn" class="mobile-continue-btn" src="assets/images/mobile-continue-now-img.png" onclick="handleGetQuotesClick(this)">
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.mobile-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    /*height: 100vh;*/
}

#mobile {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 9999;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}
```

If I change `focus-alert.style.bottom = 25%` to `20%` that centers on my screen but obviously wont for his. So just wondering how to make it centered in the middle?

Answer (score 0):

Hello can you try `margin:50% auto 50% auto;`  on image style, add it in your script that will help you to center image on middle of screen

Comment: Thank you for your help. It makes the image transition just go from the bottom to the top but it goes off the screen

Comment: can you tell me the usefulness of this variable  `focus-alert`

Comment: It applies to two different HTML elements that I have defined for both mobile and desktop.